# Problems with my JS array undefined x 7

Tags: javascript

I have an array im trying to loop through to create a new type of array specific to my current page.

My array looks like this:

```
 //$_SESSION['data'] =
 Array ( 
        [0] => 1 
        [1] => 0 
        [2] => Tom 
        [8] => 1 
        [4] => 1 
        [5] => Array ( 
                        [7] => Array ( 
                                    [0] => Andrew 
                                    [1] => 1 
                                    [2] => 1 
                                    [4] => 0 
                                    [5] => avatar.jpg 
                                    [6] => 1 
                                    ) 
                    ) 
        [6] => Array ( [0] => 1 
                       [1] => 2 
                     ) 
 )
```

So in my JS file i have this:

```
var stats = <? echo json_encode($_SESSION['data'][5]); ?> ; //this is the array 

my_data = new Array();
for(var key in stats){

    if(key in my_data){} else { //prevent double entry

    my_data[key] = new Array();
    my_data[key][0] = stats[key][6]; 
    my_data[key][1] = stats[key][5];
    my_data[key][2] = stats[key][2]; 
    my_data[key][3] = stats[key][0];
    }
}

console.log(my_data);
```

Now in console.log i get this :

```
[undefined × 7, Array[4]
 0: "1"
 1: "avatar.jpg"
 2: "1"
 3: "Andrew"
 length: 4
 __proto__: Array[0]
 ]
```

I'm wondering why it is saying undefined x7?

Comment: What does `<? echo $_SESSION['data'][5]); ?>` end up as?

Comment: It shows:
Array ( [7] => Array ( [0] => Andrew [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [4] => 0 [5] => avatar.jpg [6] => 1 ) )  thats with using print_r()

Comment: @Dave: you're clearly omitting or changing code, because there's an extra `)` in that code which would cause a syntax error in PHP.

Comment: @Len theres two open brackets and two closed where is the extra ) in that comment ? Look carefully theres an array in side the array.

Comment: @Dave: I'm referring to the original code, i.e. `<? echo $_SESSION['data'][5]); ?>`. Note the unmatched `)`.

Comment: @Len ah yeh - its cos i didn't copy paste i wrote it in to the question.

Comment: It doesn't matter what `print_r` says, what does the JavaScript look like?

Comment: @muistooshort {"7":{"0":"Andrew","1":"1","2":"1","4":"0","5":"avatar.jpg","6":"1"}}

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184581/javascript-array-numerical-key-resulting-in-excess-undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use JSON??

```
var stats = <? echo json_encode($_SESSION['data'][5]); ?> ;
```

YOu can now iterate normally.

```
for (x in stats){
     console.log(stats[x]);
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Yes, you will get 'x7 undefined'. This is because you are directly setting the 8th entry in the js array. (key == 7 in the iteration of for-loop) First 7 entries are essentially undefined.

If you want to use the first few indices, use `array.push(..)` or manually set the last index using `array[array.length] = new_object;`

Comment: Tried that but didn't seem to change much i still get 7 undefined in my console.log =/

Comment: ['data'][5] holds:  {"7":{"0":"Andrew","1":"1","2":"1","4":"0","5":"avatar.jpg","6":"1"}}

Comment: I'm agree with you in JSON serialization but for creating a new object, he should use object instead of array, I think.

Comment: Regardless, the way he iterates over it will remain the same.

Comment: @Thrustmaster hi - i was away today so only just replied... wouldn't array[array.length] just define a key's number? Its a little confusing how that works .. i'm unfamiliar with it o_0

Comment: It would access the element beyond the last too :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to serialize your object to JSON:

```
var stats = <? echo json_encode($_SESSION['data'][5]); ?> ;
```

And then...

The problem because you want to create an array with 7 keys. For example:

```
var boo = [];
boo[7] = new Array();
```

so JavaScript is going to create an array with 7 sections and then you have an array with 7 `undefined` values!

Actually you need an `object` not an `array`.

Try this code:

```
my_data = {};
for(var key in stats){

   if(!my_data[key]) { //prevent double entry
        my_data[key] = [];
        my_data[key][0] = stats[key][6]; 
        my_data[key][1] = stats[key][5];
        my_data[key][2] = stats[key][2]; 
        my_data[key][3] = stats[key][0];
   } 
}

console.log(my_data);
```

I just changed the `my_data` from `array` to `object`.